Full house probability
I am trying to calculate the probability of a full house with replacement from a standard deck of $52$ cards.
Using the stars and bars method, I know that the total outcomes possible are $^{56}C_5$ ($51$ bars and $5$ stars).
Now, to calculate the number of ways a full house can be formed, I did $13\cdot12\cdot^4C_2\cdot^{4}C_3$.
But, I do not get the right answer from this approach and I'm wondering where I went wrong.
This question is not a duplicate of Probability of getting a full house, because the latter assumes that the cards are drawn without replacement.
Some clarifications based on comments:

Duplicate cards are allowed.
Five of a kind doesn't count. There needs to be two ranks in the hand of five.


This question is similar to: Probability of getting a full house. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It is different because that question assumes without replacement. Mine doesn't.

If you select with replacement, are you allowing the same card to be selected more than once?  For instance, is $7\clubsuit, 7\clubsuit, \color{red}{7\diamondsuit}, \color{red}{J\heartsuit}, J\spadesuit$ an acceptable hand or do you require three different cards of one rank and two different cards of another rank?

Yes, I'm allowing the same card to be selected more than once.

Can I ask why you want to calculate the probability with replacement? I don't understand how it is relevant to poker if you allow the same card to appear multiple times in a hand.

yea I suppose the question can be rephrased as "What is the probability of getting 3 cards of one rank and 2 cards of another from a 52 card deck with replacement?"- a full house generally wouldn't have duplicate cards. I do not impose this restriction here.

Please revise your question so that it reflects what you said in the comments.  Also, please show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.

Stars and Bars isn't useful here because the various combinations are not equally probable.  Better to consider ordered hands,  which are equally probable, and there are $52^5$ of these

Note: I assume that,  as in regular poker,  superior hands don't count.  That is, five Aces would be Five of a Kind,  and not a Full House. But you should clarify.

Does five of a kind count as a full house?

No, it does not. There needs to be 2 ranks present in the hand of five.

If you are drawing with replacement, it may be easier to consider ordered draws. The total number of these is $52^5$.
To count the number of full houses, there are $13$ ways to select the value that has $3$ cards in the hand (call this value $A$), and $12$ ways to select the value that has $2$ cards in the hand (call this value $B$). There are then $\binom{5}{2}$ ways to pick which of the cards is $B$ (the rest will be $A$). Once this is done, we just need to select a suit for each card, which is done in $4^5$ ways.
Overall,
$$P = \frac{(13) (12) \binom{5}{2} (4)^5}{52^5} = \boxed{\frac{120}{28561}}$$

One follow up question, why is it easier to consider ordered draws over unordered ones? What would the approach be if we assumed unordered draws?

@secretrevaler The main problem with counting unordered hands is that not all are equally likely. In particular, you can imagine that getting, e.g., $5$ of the exact same card is much less likely than getting $5$ unique cards, even though both are a single (unordered) hand.
